# Return Json Encode not set

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have a simple ajax request which gets a json encode array but it keeps telling me its not set... im thinking i have the return in the wrong place but am not sure where i put it... this is my function:

```
//Browser Support Code
function ajaxFunction(url,data){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){
            var response = ajaxRequest.responseText

        }
    }   
    queryString = "?dta="+data;
    ajaxRequest.open("GET", url + queryString, true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null);
return(response);   
}
```

I then call the function like this:

```
    var result = ajaxFunction('call.php','1');
    alert(result);
```

The response is working as in console it says:

```
{"stage1":"550","stage2":"1500","stage3":"2000","total":"1"}
```

But I'm getting: response is not defined

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 resons why response is undefined:

- syntax: it is defined in inner function, so it is not visible in outer scope. So your `return (response)` actually is return (window.response)
- logical: the response is set in asynchronous callback, so when you synchronous function returns it would not be set even if you define it in the  ajaxFunction itself.

To fix it have callback that will eventually return result. Check how [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) return it result by calling `success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)` passed as argument to the function.

You can also force synchronous requests by passing "false" for third (isAsync) parameter of open call check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536648%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

Comment: So if i put the return in the if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){} then itll be ok?

Comment: Great now im even more confused :P Though i had worked it out ! :( All i ever find is jquery examples - its annoying

Comment: Look at JQuery examples and copy into your code. You are trying to do jQuery.ajax call by hand - so there is nothing wrong to see how it could be done. Also MDN link have plenty of samples of using raw XmlHttpRequest.

Comment: I think i got it to work just a quick question. I return the json_encode, but how do i convert that back to an array to use ?

Comment: JSON.parse (or for older browsers there is implementation on http://json.org, as well as jQuery.parseJSON).